# sass @for within @each, where @for is using key, value pair of @each

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I was not able to find the answer to my question: WTF - why?!

Variables

```
$breakpointNames: (xs, sm, md, lg, xl);
$breakpointSizes: (480px, 667px, 845px, 1024px, 1280px);
$breakpoints: createMapOutOfLists($breakpointNames, $breakpointSizes);
$masonryLayoutColumnsCount: (2, 2, 3, 4, 4);
$masonryLayoutColumns: createMapOutOfLists($breakpointNames, 
$masonryLayoutColumnsCount);
```

Mixin

```
@mixin media($min, $max: false) {
    @if $max == false {
        @if $min == xs {
            @media (min-width: 0px) {
                @content;
            }
        }
        @media (min-width: #{map-get($breakpoints,$min)}) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else if $min == 0 {
        @media (max-width: (#{map-get($breakpoints,$max)} - 1)) {
            @content;
        }
    } @else {
        @media (min-width: #{map-get($breakpoints,$min)}) and (max-width: (#{map-get($breakpoints,$max)} - 1)) {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this:

```
@each $breakpoint, $column-count in $masonryLayoutColumns {
    @include media($breakpoint) {
        .masonry-tile {
            width: 100% / $column-count;
        }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        @include media($breakpoint) {
            .masonry-tile:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                -webkit-order: $i;
                order: $i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That threw following Error:

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
../../../app/Resources/assets/sass/functions/_map_generators.scss
Error: 2 is not an integer.
    on line 4 of 
../../../app/Resources/assets/sass/functions/_map_generators.scss
>> merge($map, (#{nth($listOfKeys, $index)}: #{nth($listOfValues, $index)}));
------------------------------------------^
```

*That the error is at a wrong place or maybe entirely wrong, is another issue and currently irrelevant - to me - right now.*

After some time of searching without results and trying to fix it on my own, I got it to work with the following:

```
@for $index from 1 through length($masonryLayoutColumns) {
    $breakpoint: nth($breakpointSizes, $index);
    $column-count: nth($masonryLayoutColumnsCount, $index);

    @include media($breakpoint) {
        .masonry-tile {
            width: 100% / $column-count;
        }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        @include media($breakpoint) {
            .masonry-tile:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                -webkit-order: $i;
                order: $i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, that works, but I don't like it.
I prefer the first version.

Is there a good reason why the first version is not working? Or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post a sample list of $masonryLayoutColumns ?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason your code didn't work is because you must be passing a string in the map that you are creating.

$column-count should be an integer, in order to do your width manipulation  `(width: 100% / $column-count;)`

I have attached a sample pen, with integer data, which will resolve your issue.

```
$masonryLayoutColumns: (
  '760px': 8,
  '990px': 12,
  '1024px': 16
);

@each $breakpoint, $column-count in $masonryLayoutColumns {
    @media(min-width: $breakpoint) {
        .masonry-tile {
            width: 100% / $column-count;
        }
    }

    @for $i from 1 through $column-count {
        @media(min-width: $breakpoint) {
            .masonry-tile:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                -webkit-order: $i;
                order: $i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLBPaP

Note: I don't have your mixin's so I am just writing a generic media query.